solana -ud gossip | grep <Validator Address> does not show anything on devnet
it's my first time posting anything on stackexchange, so please ignore any mistakes I make.
I am trying to run a validator node on solana devnet. The node is working fine:
solana -ud gossip | grep  returns as it should
solana catchup  returns as it should
I have created a vote account, and a stake account as well. However, whenever I try to see my account using solana -ud gossip | grep , or even solana -ud validators --keep-unstaked-delinquents | grep , it does not show anything. What could be the problem?
